# Warning: Function will always return True

Tags: c++, function, boolean

I have an isPrime function that is always returning true, regardless of the inputted number. This is the same for a couple other bool functions in my program.

My simple isPrime function:

```
bool isPrime(mpz_class num)
{
    bool prime = true;

    for (int i=2; i<num; i++)
        if (num % i == 0)
            prime = false;
    return prime ;
}
```

Calling it (I suspect this is where the problem is but I don't know what the problem is):

```
do
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter Prime 1: ";
            getline(cin, sa);
            isNum(sa);
            firstPrime = sa;
        }
        while(!isNum);
    isPrime(firstPrime);
    }
    while(!isPrime);
```

The isNum function is also returning "true" every time.

Runtime error:

```
warning: the address of 'void isNum(std::string)' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]|
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: Can you show us `isNum()`?

Comment: What do you believe that `!isPrime` and `!isNum` does? Those are functions and they take arguments. Also, the error message is *not* telling you that the function will always return true. It tells you something different.

Comment: `while(!isPrime)` The error refers to this line, where you're checking if the address of this function equals to zero (which will never be the case).

Comment: You need to brush up on how to use functions and their return values.

Comment: Function calls require parentheses. `isPrime` refers to the function and evaluates to its address; it doesn't call it. `isPrime(n)` would be a call. Once you fix that, you'll need to clean up your program logic.

Comment: Can the `mpz_class` be treated like a number, for example does the class overload the `%` operator?

Comment: Your check for prime includes all even numbers after 2.  FYI, all primes after 2 are odd.  Change the increment from `i++` to `i+=2`. But you'll have to figure out how to check the value 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the return value from the call to isNum() before you can check it in the while look. What you're doing now with

```
    while(!isNum)
```

is that you're checking the address of the function and not it's return type. What you probably mean to do is something like this:

```
    bool isPrimeRetVal;
    do
    {
        bool isNumRetVal;
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter Prime 1: ";
            getline(cin, sa);
            isNumRetVal = isNum(sa);
            firstPrime = sa;
        }
        while(!isNumRetVal);
        isPrimeRetVal = isPrime(firstPrime);
    }
    while(!isPrimeRetVal);
```

Note the same issue with while(!isPrime).

Comment: there's no need for these `retval` variables. You can just call the functions in the `while` conditions

Comment: Yes, that's very true. However, it still illustrates the point.

Answer (score 2):

You ignore the return value of `isPrime` and instead check the *value* of `isPrime` (which doesn't change, it's always a valid function).

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function by merely mentioning its name, e.g. with `while (!isNum)`.

The function name in that context evaluates to a pointer to that function. Since all non-null pointers evaluate to boolean `true` and a pointer to any function cannot be equal to the null pointer, `isNum` always evaluates to `true` and `!isNum` is always false.

Instead of this:

```
do { ... isPrime(x); } while (!isPrime);
```

you need to write something more like this:

```
do { ... } while (!isPrime(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

These two lines:

```
isPrime(firstPrime);

while(!isPrime);
```

combine to suggest you're not clear on how functions are called in C++. The first line calls the function and then throws the result away. The second line doesn't even call the function, it just looks at its address (which will never be zero).

You probably want:

```
while(!isPrime(firstPrime));
```

This passes `firstPrime` to the function, and then looks at the return value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using return value of isPrime function. IsPrime is a function and you should store its value in some variable and use that variable in while loop.

The same goes with the isNum variable.